# Elements Floated Right do not activate Transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to get elements to transition onscreen. For example purposes I have set them to transition on page load.

The elements that are not floated work perfectly fine. However, the elements that have been floated right (They have the class `exleft` because they should be expanding leftward) do not transition.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/redstone_herder/7nzpnd8e/)

HTML:

```
<div id="templatebox">
  <div class="ribbon exright" id="r1">
  </div>
  <div class="ribbon exleft" id="r2">
  </div>
  <div class="ribbon exright" id="r3">
  </div>
  <div class="ribbon exleft" id="r4">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#templatebox{
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.ribbon{
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.exleft{
  right: -1200px;
  left: 0px;
  margin-right: -100px;
  float: right;
}
.exright{
  left: -1200px;
  right: 0px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

#r1{
  background-color: red;
}
#r2{
  background-color: green;
}
#r3{
  background-color: blue;
  top: 170px;
}
#r4{
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 170px;
}
```

JS:

```
var ribbons = document.getElementsByClassName("ribbon");
for(var i=0, j=ribbons.length; i<j; i++){
  ribbons[i].style.right = "0px";
  ribbons[i].style.left = "0px";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The floated ribbon has both a left and right attribute value set. If both attributes are set to a pixel value, only the left value will be used.

By setting

```
left: auto;
```

You can manipulate the right value and it will work as expected.

Here is an updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ym5p7y6v/